# How to make Vuejs work on a local Apache installation?

Tags: vue.js

I created a new Vuejs 2 project that uses the router and I built it using `npm run build` then  uploaded my `/dist` folder to `~/public_html` folder which is accessed like so: `http://localhost/~myusername/dist` however when I access a router link or something I'm redirected to a link like this `http://localhost/img/viejs.jpg`

I tried creating a .htaccess file and adding this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

No difference. Notice my apache uses that `localhost/~username/` thing. I guess that is the problem and don't know how to add it to the htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
base: '/~myusername/'
```

to your router configuration. See: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base

Comment: thank you. Where is the router configuration? Is it in `src/router/index.js` ?